# Аналог JButton на SFML c++

Tags: c++, sfml

Не могу понять каким образом в теории можно реализовать аналог JButton на SFML для моего небольшого проекта. Так как для меню нужно много переключателей параметров,
будет проблематично для каждой кнопки прописывать отдельный класс.
Хотелось бы что бы код выглядел примерно таким образом:

```cpp
Button button("надпись на кнопке", "путь до спрайта кнопки");
button.addAction(new Action() {
     std::cout << "hello world! \n";
});
```

Comment: Можно написать свой UI тулкит. Существующие либо монструозные, либо недопиленные.

Comment: Создаёте класс кнопки, который будет содержать `std::vector<std::function<void(void)>>` и добавьте функцию `addAction`